# Update OpenSSH Server in 12.04?

Tags: openssh

I'm having hard time updating openssh-server in ubuntu 12.04, I stupidly downloaded .deb file for 14.04 and of course it didn't work :/

I've tried sudo apt-get -f install, it just removed my openssh

**Here's the output installing openssh 6.6**

```
vagrant@precise64:~$ sudo dpkg -i openssh-server_6.6p1-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package openssh-server.
(Reading database ... 84054 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking openssh-server (from openssh-server_6.6p1-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of openssh-server:
 openssh-server depends on libc6 (>= 2.17); however:
  Version of libc6 on system is 2.15-0ubuntu10.5.
 openssh-server depends on libck-connector0 (>= 0.2.1); however:
  Package libck-connector0 is not installed.
 openssh-server depends on init-system-helpers (>= 1.13~); however:
  Package init-system-helpers is not installed.
 openssh-server depends on openssh-client (= 1:6.6p1-2ubuntu1); however:
  Version of openssh-client on system is 1:5.9p1-5ubuntu1.3.
 openssh-server depends on sysv-rc (>= 2.88dsf-24) | file-rc (>= 0.8.16); however:
  Version of sysv-rc on system is 2.88dsf-13.10ubuntu11.1.
  Package file-rc is not installed.
 openssh-server depends on lsb-base (>= 4.1+Debian3); however:
  Version of lsb-base on system is 4.0-0ubuntu20.3.
 openssh-server depends on openssh-sftp-server; however:
  Package openssh-sftp-server is not installed.
dpkg: error processing openssh-server (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Processing triggers for ufw ...
```

Comment: Can you explain why you are trying to update OpenSSH or which version you expect to be able to update to? It looks to me like you already have the latest version available for 12.04, so no update will be possible using apt-get.

Comment: He is probably trying to upgrade due to a security risk associated to pre openssh 6.6 versions. Ubuntu 12.04 only upgrades to 5.9 and leaves the server **Non PCI compliant**. Did you ever find a solution for this Darick?

Answer (score 2):

The Code you Input:

```
sudo dpkg -i openssh-server_6.6p1-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Should install the OpenSSH-Server and not Remove it. Anyway, If you want to install it the Correct way, Open Up a Terminal Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and Type:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

and it will install The OpenSSH-Server, and if it already Installed, It Will Update it and if it's up to date then nothing will be done, Also, If You have trouble with the Command Above Try:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And As listed above, Ubuntu Upgrade OpenSSH-Server to an Older Version than the Latest, So To Install the Latest, First we need to remove any existing old OpenSSH-Server, Bring up a Command Prompt Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and Type the Following, Pressing Enter after Each Line:

```
sudo apt-get remove openssh-server
```

and Then to Install the latest

```
wget http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/openssh-6.6p1.tar.gz    

tar -xvf openssh-6.6p1.tar.gz    

cd openssh-6.6p1    

./configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc/ssh    

--with-md5-passwords --with-privsep-path=/var/lib/sshd    

sudo make install
```

And you should now Have OpenSSH-Server 6.6 P1, To Check, Type in a Terminal:

```
sshd -V
```

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 only upgrades up to openssh 5.9. https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+source/openssh

Comment: Already Editing my answer..

Comment: @Lisandro Done Editing =)

Answer (score 1):

This is not the original solution but a workaround to get the latest openssh-server on Ubuntu.
Execute these lines in your Terminal:

> sudo echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic security universe" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install openssh-server=1:6.6p1-2ubuntu1

Comment: are you sure you don't mean sudo echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe" >> /etc/apt/sources.list ??

and this line is already present in the file.

Comment: Nope now it should be utopic

Comment: For people who still run 12.10 and want to upgrade openssh: `deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic main universe`

Answer (score 1):

Since I cannot comment, I ran into some issues with this, same as above but with some extra steps to prevent getting locked out.

Same steps as above:

```
wget http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/openssh-6.6p1.tar.gz    

tar -xvf openssh-6.6p1.tar.gz    

cd openssh-6.6p1    

./configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc/ssh    

--with-md5-passwords --with-privsep-path=/var/lib/sshd    

sudo make install
```

Then make sure you restart ssh!

```
sudo service ssh start
```

Unlock and set to a random password (you will still get .pem passwordless access)

```
sudo passwd -u ubuntu       
sudo passwd    ubuntu
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to use the latest OpenSSL (1.0.2a) so I had to build that first ([Upgrade OpenSSL on Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429385/upgrade-openssl-on-ubuntu-12-04)). Then I had to help the OpenSSH figure out where my local ssl source was located (--with-ssl-dir=/usr/local/ssl).

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc/ssh --with-md5-passwords 
--with-privsep-path=/var/lib/sshd --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl/lib 
--with-ssl-dir=/usr/local/ssl
```