# installing Clamav-0.98.3 on ubuntu 12.04 for the first time

Tags: 12.04, clamav

I've tried to install clamav but everytime i get this error 'OpenSSL not found'. I'm new to ubuntu and i don't know what to do. Can somebody please hepl me ?

Comment: How are trying to install Clamav?  Software Center, command line?

Answer (score 0):

Open Terminal Ctl-Alt-T and enter this

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install clamav clamtk
```

It should install any dependencies needed to complete the installation.

Answer (score 0):

Read this if you want to know more about the error:

http://blog.clamav.net/2014/02/introducing-openssl-as-dependency-to.html

The solution to your Problem:

a) Install openssl dependency first on your pc and to do so read following

[Upgrade OpenSSL on Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429385/upgrade-openssl-on-ubuntu-12-04)

b) after successful installation of openSSL  install clamav by following commands

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install clamav (if you want non-gui package) or

sudo apt-get install clamav clamtk (if you want a gui based package)...
```

If the above procedure dosen't work then download `clamtk` directly from Ubuntu Software Center