# How to check which OpenSSL version is use by Apache on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, apache2, openssl

I have installed Ubuntu12.04 on my machine and it got [heartBleed](http://heartbleed.com) version of OpenSSL 1.0.1. So I uninstalled OpenSSL 1.0.1 and install new 1.0.1g version by refering [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429385/upgrade-openssl-on-ubuntu-12-04) link.

Now I want to confirm that the "Apache 2.2.22" available on Ubuntu 12.04 is using 1.0.1g and not 1.0.1 version of OpenSSL. How will I confirm this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
$ apt-cache policy openssl
openssl: Installed: xxx
```

"*Installed: xxx*" shows the currently installed version of openssl. Heartbleed is fixed in the following package versions (or later):

**Ubuntu 13.10:**
    libssl1.0.0 1.0.1e-3ubuntu1.2

**Ubuntu 12.10:**
    libssl1.0.0 1.0.1c-3ubuntu2.7

**Ubuntu 12.04 LTS:**
    libssl1.0.0 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.12

If your installed package version is lower than these, then your system is vulnerable to Heartbleed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Will this ensure that the Apache I am using (which is available on Ubuntu) is using upgraded OpenSSL1.0.1g? I can see `Installed: 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.16` on my machine now.

Comment: Yes. Make sure you are doing regular security updates - heartbleed is not the only security vulnerability to affect 12.04.

Comment: Ok great :). What are the other security vulnerability to affect 12.04, Can you share any link or document? Thank you very much :)

Comment: Here: [Ubuntu 12.04 security notices](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/precise/) Note that is just the first page, if you scroll down you will see that (as of July 2014) there are **12 pages of vulnerabilities in 12.04**. Everyone should do regular security updates.