# Ubuntu 15.04 OpenSSL Heartbleed

Tags: server, 15.04, openssl

I spun up a new Rackspace server with Ubuntu Server 15.04, choosing 15.04 believing that I was getting the latest and greatest software. However, after some investigation, it seems that 15.04 ships with OpenSSL 1.0.1f, built on Jan 6, 2014. According to everything I've read, this version is susceptible to the Heartbleed bug.

What is the best way to about updating OpenSSL on 15.04 without interfering with default apt packages?

**Update:** I've found these explanations to be helpful.

- https://serverfault.com/a/587603/154612
- https://askubuntu.com/a/504932/374500

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, 1.0.1f-1 was built in 2014.01.06.
However 15.04 ships with 1.0.1f-1ubuntu11, built on 2015.03.19.
Please review the [changelog](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/o/openssl/openssl_1.0.1f-1ubuntu11/changelog).